# How can I add tab to all lines between <a> tags

Tags: php, regex

```
$update_text= preg_replace("/(<a[^>]*>)\s*(.*?)\s*(<\/a>)/s", "$1\n\t$2\n$3", $text);
```

Have this :

```html
<a href="#" class="example">
<img src="bg1.jpg">
text text
</a>
<a href="#" class="example">
text text
<img src="bg2.jpg">
text text
</a>
<a href="#" class="example">
<img src="bg3.jpg">
</a>
```

Want this :

```html
<a href="#" class="example">
  <img src="bg1.jpg">
  text text
</a>
<a href="#" class="example">
  text text
  <img src="bg2.jpg">
  text text
</a>
<a href="#" class="example">
  <img src="bg3.jpg">
</a>
```

https://regex101.com/r/qo2N22/3

I want to add `\t` all `$2` lines but only applied to the first line. Could anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Post the original code, a sample input and desired output.

Comment: sorry I put code into the post but removed some codes. try to add.

Comment: updated all post.

Comment: [Why parsing HTML with a regex is not possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: Use a parser and just append a tab to the start of the node value.... or depending on the parser you might be able to have it format your output.

Comment: With your current approach you'll need to use `preg_replace_callback` and then explode the `$2` on new lines.

Comment: You cannot see tabs on a browser (html), use a txt file to monitor the changes

Comment: @Pedro Lobito I don't want to see on browser. I want see on source code.

Comment: @chris85 Thank you so much. I did it with preg_replace_callback

Answer (score -1):

I did it with preg_replace_callback. Thanks @chris85 for suggestion.

```
$update_text= preg_replace_callback("/(<a[^>]*>)\s*(.*?)\s*(<\/a>)/s", function($match) {
      $values = explode("\n",$match[2]);
      foreach ($values as $value) {
          $newmatch .= "\n\t".$value;
      }
      return $match[1].$newmatch."\n".$match[3];
    }, $text);
```

Comment: **Never parse html with a regex**, use a proper html  parser like php DOMDocument or similar.